# Wordpress website can't find URL without trailing forward slash

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm using wordpress in my website and I have issues with the short URLs. For example the URL

```
mywebsite/page/
```

works fine and sends me to the page. But the URL

```
mywebsite/page (without the '/')
```

gives me a blank page.
This happens in my online server (one.com) but not on my localhost.
It happens with all the pages, so it's not because of conflicting URLs.

I assume the problem is in the server settings, but what is it exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try and change your permanent links settings under Control Panel -> Settings -> Permalinks? Maybe you have your own structere set?

Cheers,
Nicolaj

**EDIT:**

Try adding this to your .htaccess file. This will force a rewrite of links without the trailing slash.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yes, but then all the links that do have a trailing / are broken

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your .htaccess file

```
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```